# Login cannot get value from req.body, leads to a problem cannot read the property 'password' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

Hope somebody can help me, plz
I cannot get the value from req.body from the form in login.hbs, and makes an report error: cannot read the property 'password' of undefined.

I have been searched for a long time, but still cannot fix it.

I have another page called register.hbs, the format is similar to login.hs, other parts are also similar, but the form in register can post the information and can be got by req.body, however, things get different in the part about login.

console report like this:
[Object: null prototype] {
account: '11@gmail.com',
password: '1234qQ'
}
undefined
undefined
[]
(node:20204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read propert

(node:20204) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are dled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

```js
//login.js
function signupbutton(){
    parent.location.href="/register";
}

function validate(){
    var username=document.getElementById('usr');
    var password=document.getElementById('pwd');
    //username and password cannot be empty
    if(username.value.trim()==""){
        alert("please fill in your account");
        username.style.border = "solid 2px blue";
        return false;
    }
    else if(password.value.trim()==""){
        alert("please enter your password");
        password.style.border = "solid 2px blue";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        //check database
       
        return auth.js;
        
    }
}


//auth.js
exports.login = async (req,res) =>{
        console.log(req.body);
        const{mail, Password} = req.body;
        
        console.log(mail);
        console.log(Password);

        db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailaddress=? ',[mail],async(error,results)=>{
          
            console.log(results);
            
            if(error){
                console.log(error); 
            }
            if(!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(Password, results[0].password)) ){
                res.status(400).render('login',{
                    message: 'Email or password is incorrect'
                })
            }
            else {
                
                const id = results[0].id;
                const token = jwt.sign({ id:id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
                    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
                });

                console.log("The token is: " + token);

                const cookieOptions = {
                    expires: new Date(
                        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                    ),
                    httpOnly: true
                }

                res.cookie('jwt',token,cookieOptions);
                res.status(200),redirect("/register");
            } 
       
        });
        

    
}


//app.js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cookieParser = require ("cookie-parser");

dotenv.config({
    path: './.env'
});

const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST, 
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE
    //online server, local host just about where the database is
});

const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './public'); 
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));

//grab the data
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.set('view engine','hbs');

db.connect((error)=>{
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
    else{
        console.log("mysql connected...")
    }
});


app.use('/', require('./routes/pages'));    

app.use('/auth',require('./routes/auth'));   

app.listen(5001, ()=>{
    console.log("Server started on Port 5001");
})


//route.js
const express = require('express');
const authController = require('../controllers/auth');


const router = express.Router();

router.post('/login',authController.login);
router.post('/register', authController.register);



module.exports = router;


//pages.js
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();



router.get('/register',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('register');
}); 

router.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="x-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"/>
        <title>Voting Platform</title>
        <link ref="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
        <script src="/js/login.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="login1">
         <div class="thesignform">
   
          <form onsubmit=" validate(); return false;" action="/auth/login" method="POST" class="login" id="login"> 
            <h1>Log in</h1>
            <img class="iconp" src="/img/icon"}}
            </div>
        </div>


</body> 
 
</html>
```

Comment: you need a [body parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) for express

Comment: It still reports the same warnings after installing the body parser

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze It can show the results from req.body, but the value cannot be stored by const { mail ,Password}= req.body